# Algorithm--How to find any number of elements in an array which the sum close to a specified value?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

1. Say there is an array which has 500 elements which all are random float numbers.
2. And there is an arbitrary value.
3. we need to collect element[s] from the array, that the sum of the element combination is as closed as possible to the value.

e.g.

```
array[187.2, 3.5, 4.5, 3459.32 ...]

value = 3.5
result = array[1]

value = 8.9
result = [array[1],array[2]]

value = 5432.43
result = [array[2],array[301], array[430]...]
```

Is the exhaustive test unavoidable?

Comment: Everyday... Everyday somebody asks about `subset sum problem`

Comment: Can you have negative numbers on the input?